# Аккордеон в slick slider. Какой код нужен для пересчета высоты .slick-list?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

Есть аккордеон в slick slider, содержимое аккордеонов разная. Все аккордеоны закрыты. Слайдер определил высоту. Для того чтобы открыть аккордеон и чтоб подгрузился весь контент в аккордеоне есть такой код что ниже. При нажатии на кнопку .slick-list принимает высоту auto, но тут возникает проблема в том что высота задается по самому обьемному слайду, в котором больше всего контента, получается что в других слайдах остается пустое место как в примере. Кто подскажет как это решить. Нужен код которой при клике на кнопку будет пересчитывать заново высоту.
https://codepen.io/DjeenGreen/pen/JjYrWNo

```
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
});

// accordion


$('.content-hide').slideUp();
$('.show-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
      wrap = $this.closest('.slide'),
      content = wrap.find('.content-hide'),
      $slider = $('.slider');

  content.slideToggle();

 $slider.find('.slick-slide').height('auto');
$slider.find('.slick-list').height('auto');
$slider.slick('setOption', null, null, true);

});
```

Нашел в интернете такой код:
$slider[0].slick.animateHeight();
Как применить?

Answer (score 0):

Скрыть элемент, тогда высота блока слайдера будет считаться правильно

```
.content-hide {
  display: none;
}
```